# Including files in a VS2010 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, include-path

Suppose I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 with the following structure:

```
ProjectFolder
|
|_FirstFolder
|   some_header.h
|
|_SecondFolder
    main.cpp
```

In order to include the *some_header.h* into *main.cpp* I have to write `#include <../FirstFolder/some_header.h>` in the that source file.

It is rather cumbersome to use the UNIX directory shortcuts like `.` and `..` and some standards like [this one](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) even prohibit to do this. Can I somehow live without the UNIX shortcuts? I would like to directly include files starting the navigation from the project folder like this `#include <FirstFolder/some_header.h>`, but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the home directory of your project as additional include directory(Project->Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories) I think this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> Additional Include Directories

Which can be found via **Properties** (of a build target) -> **Configuration Properties** -> **C/C++**.

There you can just add the relative path to **FirstFolder**, relative to the project root. Having done this, `#include <some_header.h>` would work.

Comment: Good answer!  I improved the formatting a bit. You can use wiki formatting characters like * and ` in your answers.